# Using preposition "for" two time in sequence is correct?

Tags: prepositions

The sentence:

> please refer the attachment **for** the contacts **for** this particular event.

Here using "for" two times in this sequence is correct?

Comment: It should be "refer *to* the attachment"; it is otherwise correct.

Comment: and it should be "Please refer *to* the attachment ..."

Comment: Why do you think that it might not be? Is there some rule that you heard or read about?

Answer (score 0):

There is noting wrong with using the preposition "for" twice in the same sentence. Nor would there be such a problem with other prepositions.

The given example, however, is rather odd and not fully natural. It woul;d be better if rephrased as:

> Please refer *to* the attachment **for** the contacts **for** this particular event.

as the comments by users Peter and Anton suggest. The original formulation:

> Please refer the attachment **for** the contacts

uses "refer" without "to" in a way which is not natural in English usage.

On the original point, here are some examples that repeat "for" and other prepositions within a sentence, but are fully valid English.

> - We will use Peterson's Blooms for the flowers for the concert.
> - I am looking for a necklace for my sister.
> - I left the bag on the beach on Thursday.
> - At the signal the aimed the gun at the target.
> - I want to find an example in the dictionary that uses the word in this way.
> - They flew over the ranch over the course of two days.
> - It was among the possibilities that the culprit would be found among the students.
> - They hurried to tell Alexander of Macedon of the defeat.